# What encoding is used for Adobe Flex profiling information?

Tags: apache-flex, profiling

I've been using the Flex memory profiler on a reasonably large application, and the Loitering objects and Object References panes are quite slow.  The speed isn't helped by all the circular references being displayed -- I'd really like to be able to restrict the visible references to those which aren't circular.

Is the format of the files saved by the memory profiler documented anywhere, or are there any better tools for extracting information from them?